Getting all search results from a google query
I am trying to get a list of all links to a particular subreddit but my problem is that the reddit api seems to only have access to the last 1000 posts.
To solve this I believe I can use a google query like this
site:https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/

This returns 64,100 results which seems to be the correct amount of posts.

The problem with this is that google has removed pagination and only 400 results if you scroll all the way to the bottom.
Google must have some official search api but I haven't been able to find it with my searching.
